# Update MyISAM sdi version

Tags: mysql, myisam, sdi

I have a schema MyISAM.
I made an update of mysql server and now if I create a new table in .sdi files i see:
"mysqld_version_id":80019
"dd_version":80017
"sdi_version":80019

The problem is in my old tables, where versions in .sdi files are:
"mysqld_version_id":80018
"dd_version":80017
sdi_version":80016

So, I can't do a restore from files (with IMPORT TABLE FROM ...), because of sdi versions are different.

How can I update my sdi files?
I tried with check table for upgrade but doesn't work.
Is my only possibility do a backup and remake tables from sql?

Comment: MyISAM is going away; convert to InnoDB.

Comment: I well know innodb (and usually i use him), but in some situations you cannot simply migrate. So, if nobody point me to a better solution, I think I'll remake tables from an sql backup.

Comment: This looks similar:  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96943 -- perhaps your case is worth a bug report:  bugs.mysql.com .  Meanwhile, what prevents moving to InnoDB?  I have some workarounds here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: I tried to restructure tables adding (and then removing) a field.
This seems to force regeneration of sdi files with the right version.

Comment: I also opened a bug on MySql (the CHECK TABLE with FOR UPGRADE option should report the table problem but doesn't)